# Program elements in main memory

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

What are the program elements that should be present in RAM when a process like a c program executable a.out is running ? Is program code also there?  And if yes what is the need of it?

Comment: [This link](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory) explains it quite well

Answer (score 1):

yes, the code a.out is present in memory when a.out is running. the instruction pointer (or register) points to the current operation being executed in memory, and most operations also advance the instruction pointer to the next operation. although, if by code you mean the original C code, this is not always the case -- only the assembled executable bytecode has to be in memory. there are flags to the compiler/linker to include the C code in the assembled output executable to make debugging easier.

if we're talking about the virtual memory space of the process, this will also include some memory-mapped io registers, some kernel-space functions, and any libraries the program requires (at least libc for your general-type operations).

Answer (score 0):

In principle the machine code is inside the process' address space, and very often in RAM. However, there are situations where the machine code is not yet in RAM, and the kernel has to load it from disk. This happens transparently, because of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Concretely, the [execve(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) syscall sets up memory mapping for the various segments in the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable binary, much like [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) does (it is the system call, with `munmap` and  `mprotect` to change the memory map).

Look at the `/proc/1234/maps` of a process 1234 to understand more, or simply run

```
  cat /proc/self/maps
```

to get the memory map of the process running that `cat`.

Comment: what does above command do and what is the interpretation I should make of that output

Comment: Try that command: it shows you a textual representation of the memory mapping (of the process executing that command). Then read the other links I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is program code also there?
```

yes your program code will be also in RAM

actualy any c program has main 3 segment in memory

```
* Data Segment
* Code Segment
* Stack and Heap areas
```

your code goes in code segment.
[image]

see [This article](http://shareprogrammingtips.com/c-language-programming-tips/structure-of-a-c-program-in-memory-how-heapstackdata-and-code-segments-are-stored-in-memory/)